# Как привести координаты LonLat в координаты для отображения на плоскости?

Tags: алгоритм

В общем рендерю карту, подскажите как координаты Lon и Lat привести к такому виду, чтобы отображать их на плоскости (без сторонних библиотек). 
В ином случае карта выглядит деформируемой. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Существуют десятки методов преобразования географичских координат в декартовы для проецирования земной поверхности на плоскость (создания карт). Выбор метода может зависеть от размера участка земной поверхности, его местоположения, назначения карты. Дополнительная сложность - выбор географического датума, то есть формы/размера эллипсоида и его положения относительно WGS84. Одна из часто используемых разновидностей преобразований - проекции Меркатора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем использую сейчас такие формулы:

```
latToCart : function(lat, zoom) {
    return (Math.floor((1-Math.log(Math.tan(lat*Math.PI/180) + 
                    1/Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180))/Math.PI)/2 *Math.pow(2,zoom)));
},

lonToCart : function(lon, zoom) {
    return Math.floor((lon + 180) / 360 * Math.pow(2, zoom)); 
},

cartToLat : function(x, y, zoom) {
    var n=Math.PI-2*Math.PI*y/Math.pow(2,z);
    return (180/Math.PI*Math.atan(0.5*(Math.exp(n)-Math.exp(-n))));
},

cartToLon : function(x, y, zoom) {
    return (x/Math.pow(2,z)*360-180);
}
```